# "Did you find" versus "have you found"

Tags: verbs, differences

What is the difference between "Did you find?" and "Have you found?"

When should I use the first sentence, and when the second one?

Comment: Related to various degrees: [When do I use present perfect instead of the simple past?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/17485/), [Present perfect tense versus past tense](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/1357/), [“I found the map” or “I have found the map”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/14534/), [When to use “have had”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/4870/), [“I just ate them” and “I've just eaten them”](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/16081/), [Perfect tense usage](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/8316/), and a few more.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

*Did you find* is the simple past and indicates that you are no longer looking for it.

*Have you found* is the present perfect and indicates a link with the present, specifically, that you could still be looking for it.