# "Did you wash your hands?" or "Have you washed your hands?" and why?

Tags: present-perfect, simple-past, present-perfect-vs-simple-past

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When do I use present perfect tense instead of the simple past?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/17485/when-do-i-use-present-perfect-tense-instead-of-the-simple-past)
>   [“Did you find” versus “have you found”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/18107/did-you-find-versus-have-you-found)

The first sentence hasn't specified time, but I have seen it.

Comment: Either is possible. It depends on the context.

Comment: Visit and join ESL http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41665/english-language-learners?referrer=Flyp9GdUZG08GxFV_g6lKw2

Comment: Please have a look at the linked questions. The [first one](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/21846/) provides a general overview of how the different tenses in English correspond to one another. The [second one](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1357/), and the related questions linked from there, address your question more directly. Lastly, the [third one](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3309/) addresses an important difference between British and American English.

Answer (score 4):

The perfect tense, used in the second sentence, indicates something done in the past, which has a continuing effect on the present. To ask the first could mean nothing, as their hands could have been washed yesterday, or maybe even today and are now dirty. The second, however, is much more effective in interrogation.